# c# console app - how to execute a function when a value not changed for x amount of time(repeating frame)

Tags: c#, console, repeat

My main problem is, I'm coding a movement simulaltor for a game,
What I want to do is, to check if the character got stuck and its position is not changing.

So What I thought is something like this:

If `Me.Location3D` is the same for `X` Amount of time -> `Me.SetLocation(Location3D.X = Location3D.X +1, Location3D.Y = Location3D.Y +1)`

```
public void Pulse(float dt)
{
    Skandia.Update();
    Me = Skandia.Me;
    if (Me == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    //This void repeats every frame of the game
    //functions should take place below
}
```

If anyone got an idea how to check the elapsed time, that'd be great.

Sadly I havent found such a specific thing on stackoverflow yet, just saying cause the topic sound pretty general.

greetings

Comment: "My main problem is, I'm coding a movement simulaltor for a game" :) Aside from that it is not yet clear what the actual problem is: clearly you should be able to store location and compare with current one to see if it was not changed over some time... It is unlikely we can figure out how to "check the elapsed time" in your program based on just sample you've provided...

Comment: Well i can compare them, thats not a problem, my problem is to check the elapsed time, since i have no function build in for that

Comment: Even less clear now - if you don't even have such method in your code how one can help you to use it? Some reading on creating game/simulation frameworks as suggested in in in pix's answer may be good starting point to implement one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working a game, you should use a main loop.
The solution is pretty simple.

Each time you get Inside this method, check the time elapsed between your actions.

You should read this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203873.aspx

**Variable-Step Game Loops**

A variable-step game calls its Update and Draw methods in a continuous loop without regard to the TargetElapsedTime. Setting Game.IsFixedTimeStep to false causes a Game to use a variable-step game loop.

**Animation and Timing**

For operations that require precise timing, such as animation, the type of game loop your game uses (fixed-step or variable-step) is important.

Using a fixed step allows game logic to use the TargetElapsedTime as its basic unit of time and assume that Update will be called at that interval. Using a variable step requires the game logic and animation code to be based on ElapsedGameTime to ensure smooth gameplay. Because the Update method is called immediately after the previous frame is drawn, the time between calls to Update can vary. Without taking the time between calls into account, the game would seem to speed up and slow down. The time elapsed between calls to the Update method is available in the Update method's gameTime parameter. You can reset the elapsed times by calling ResetElapsedTime.

When using a variable-step game loop, you should express rates—such as the distance a sprite moves—in game units per millisecond (ms). The amount a sprite moves in any given update can then be calculated as the rate of the sprite times the elapsed time. Using this approach to calculate the distance the sprite moved ensures that the sprite will move consistently if the speed of the game or computer varies.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually comment with a short answer like this but I'm short 3 reputation.
My solution is just track it with a variable and reset when needed, in your case when character moves.

```
    Double elapsedTimeInMS = 0;
    private void YourTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Every 10 ms
        elapsedTimeInMS += 10;
    }

    private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //In your case the character moves
        MessageBox.Show(elapsedTimeInMS + "");
        elapsedTimeInMS = 0;
    }
```

**After edit** 
You would need to implement a check in your timer to see if elapsed time isn't getting too high.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(elapsedTimeInMS + ""); this is ugly
Then you do not expose the timeroption.

Comment: @pix This is as an example, its only about tracking the time. He has to implement it himself. **Edit:** The button click (and MessageBox) was for me to check if it worked, has nothing to do with his code/my answer.